# ZXing Phonegap Plugin doesn't return to application after successful scan

Tags: android, cordova, zxing

I'm implementing the ZXing Phonegap plugin with the latest version of Codova (1.5.0) and have the plugin mostly working.

Trouble is when the Barcode is scanned successfully it doesn't return to my success call back but instead displays the standard Share / Lookup buttons that come with the binary ZXing app.

Anyone know why this would be?

Below is the LogCat output for the execution of the app and I can see the CaptureActivityHandler messages.

```
            04-02 15:03:14.107: I/CordovaLog(21260): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
            04-02 15:03:14.107: D/DroidGap(21260): DroidGap.onCreate()
            04-02 15:03:14.117: D/DroidGap(21260): DroidGap.loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
            04-02 15:03:14.117: D/DroidGap(21260): DroidGap: url=file:///android_asset/www/index.html baseUrl=file:///android_asset/www/
            04-02 15:03:14.117: D/DroidGap(21260): DroidGap.init()
            04-02 15:03:14.237: D/Database(21260): dbopen(): path = /data/data/quidsin.qpeesmerchantapp/databases/webview.db, flag = 6, file size = 15360
            04-02 15:03:14.247: D/Database(21260): dbopen(): path = /data/data/quidsin.qpeesmerchantapp/databases/webview.db, mode: wal, disk free size: 827 M, handle: 0x34d260
            04-02 15:03:14.277: D/Database(21260): dbopen(): path = /data/data/quidsin.qpeesmerchantapp/databases/webviewCache.db, flag = 6, file size = 6144
            04-02 15:03:14.397: I/Database(21260): sqlite returned: error code = 0, msg = Recovered 18 frames from WAL file /data/data/quidsin.qpeesmerchantapp/databases/webviewCache.db-wal
            04-02 15:03:14.397: D/Database(21260): dbopen(): path = /data/data/quidsin.qpeesmerchantapp/databases/webviewCache.db, mode: wal, disk free size: 827 M, handle: 0x34eed0
            04-02 15:03:14.628: D/skia(21260): htcFlashPlugin::htcFlashPlugin
            04-02 15:03:14.628: D/qct(21260): [WebView.WebView] >> Enable Shutdown = true
            04-02 15:03:14.638: D/qct(21260): [PreConnectionManager.PreConnectionManager] >> TCP_PRE_CONNECT = false
            04-02 15:03:14.698: D/qct(21260): [RequestQueue.ActivePool.ActivePool] >> Enable Shutdown = true
            04-02 15:03:14.698: D/qct(21260): [IdleCache.IdleCache] >> IDLE_CACHE_MAX = 40
            04-02 15:03:14.758: D/ATRecorder(21260): com.htc.autotest.dlib.RecordEngine in loader dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@4053c1e0
            04-02 15:03:14.788: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(21260): Ignore this event
            04-02 15:03:15.018: W/webcore(21260): Not supported in this case.
            04-02 15:03:15.018: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(21260): Ignore this event
            04-02 15:03:15.348: D/webkit-timers(21260): [JWebCoreJavaBridge::resume] >> do resume
            04-02 15:03:15.478: D/szipinf(21260): Initializing inflate state
            04-02 15:03:15.478: D/szipinf(21260): Initializing inflate state
            04-02 15:03:15.478: D/szipinf(21260): Initializing inflate state
            04-02 15:03:15.478: D/szipinf(21260): Initializing zlib to inflate
            04-02 15:03:15.478: D/szipinf(21260): Initializing zlib to inflate
            04-02 15:03:15.528: D/szipinf(21260): Initializing zlib to inflate
            04-02 15:03:17.991: I/Database(21260): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27206 of [42537b6056]
            04-02 15:03:19.142: D/RequestQueue(21260): setProxyConfig: wifi enabled.
            04-02 15:03:19.142: D/RequestQueue(21260): setProxyConfig mProxyHost=null
            04-02 15:03:19.422: D/webkit-timers(21260): [JWebCoreJavaBridge::pause] >> do pause
            04-02 15:03:19.903: D/Database(21260): dbopen(): path = /data/data/quidsin.qpeesmerchantapp/databases/barcode_scanner_history.db, flag = 6, file size = 4096
            04-02 15:03:19.913: D/Database(21260): dbopen(): path = /data/data/quidsin.qpeesmerchantapp/databases/barcode_scanner_history.db, mode: wal, disk free size: 827 M, handle: 0x4db5a8
            04-02 15:03:19.953: D/Database(21260): dbclose(): path = /data/data/quidsin.qpeesmerchantapp/databases/barcode_scanner_history.db, handle = 0x4db5a8
            04-02 15:03:20.073: I/AudioSystem(21260): getting audio flinger
            04-02 15:03:20.093: I/AudioSystem(21260): returning new audio session id
            04-02 15:03:20.093: D/IAudioFlinger(21260): newAudioSessionId In
            04-02 15:03:20.103: D/IAudioFlinger(21260): newAudioSessionId Out, id = 721
            04-02 15:03:22.395: D/CameraConfigurationManager(21260): Default preview format: 17/yuv420sp
            04-02 15:03:22.425: D/CameraConfigurationManager(21260): Screen resolution: Point(960, 540)
            04-02 15:03:22.425: D/CameraConfigurationManager(21260): preview-size-values parameter: 1280x720,960x544,800x480,640x480,480x320
            04-02 15:03:22.425: D/CameraConfigurationManager(21260): Camera resolution: Point(960, 544)
            04-02 15:03:22.425: D/CameraConfigurationManager(21260): Setting preview size: Point(960, 544)
            04-02 15:03:22.886: D/CameraManager(21260): Calculated framing rect: Rect(240, 90 - 720, 450)
            *** SNIPPED GC ***
            04-02 15:03:28.501: D/CaptureActivityHandler(21260): Got decode succeeded message
            04-02 15:03:28.541: D/Database(21260): dbopen(): path = /data/data/quidsin.qpeesmerchantapp/databases/barcode_scanner_history.db, flag = 6, file size = 4096
            04-02 15:03:28.551: D/Database(21260): dbopen(): path = /data/data/quidsin.qpeesmerchantapp/databases/barcode_scanner_history.db, mode: wal, disk free size: 827 M, handle: 0x51ec10
            04-02 15:03:28.711: D/Database(21260): dbclose(): path = /data/data/quidsin.qpeesmerchantapp/databases/barcode_scanner_history.db, handle = 0x51ec10
            04-02 15:03:28.741: D/Database(21260): dbopen(): path = /data/data/quidsin.qpeesmerchantapp/databases/barcode_scanner_history.db, flag = 6, file size = 4096
            04-02 15:03:28.741: D/Database(21260): dbopen(): path = /data/data/quidsin.qpeesmerchantapp/databases/barcode_scanner_history.db, mode: wal, disk free size: 827 M, handle: 0x51ec10
            04-02 15:03:28.821: D/Database(21260): dbclose(): path = /data/data/quidsin.qpeesmerchantapp/databases/barcode_scanner_history.db, handle = 0x51ec10
            04-02 15:03:28.851: D/MediaPlayer(21260): start() in
            04-02 15:03:28.901: D/MediaPlayer(21260): start() out
            04-02 15:03:28.952: D/Camera(21260): HTC_CALLBACK: callbackType=5 arg1=1 arg2=0 mHtcCallback=null
            04-02 15:03:30.523: D/ProductResultInfoRetriever(21260): Consuming entity
            04-02 15:03:36.008: W/KeyCharacterMap(21260): Can't open keycharmap file
            04-02 15:03:36.008: W/KeyCharacterMap(21260): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/cy8c-touchscreen.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65538.devname='cy8c-touchscreen'
            04-02 15:03:36.008: I/KeyCharacterMap(21260): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
            04-02 15:03:36.018: D/CaptureActivityHandler(21260): Got restart preview message
            *** SNIPPED GC ***
            04-02 15:03:36.979: W/KeyCharacterMap(21260): Can't open keycharmap file
            04-02 15:03:36.979: W/KeyCharacterMap(21260): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/cy8c-touchscreen.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65538.devname='cy8c-touchscreen'
            04-02 15:03:36.979: I/KeyCharacterMap(21260): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
            04-02 15:03:37.099: V/FlashlightManager(21260): This device does not support control of a flashlight
            04-02 15:03:37.109: D/Camera-JNI(21260): native_release: context=0x3a7848 camera=0x4be5c8
            04-02 15:03:37.620: D/webkit-timers(21260): [JWebCoreJavaBridge::resume] >> do resume
```

TIA

Rob